# Is it possible to override Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() at runtime?

Tags: c#, appdomain

I am working on a "debug dispatcher" C# program that is a debug assistance tool. This is not a new application; it has been a part of this project and invaluable to debugging it for some time. However, it has some limitations, which I have been trying to address to enable a more complete debugging experience.

This debug dispatcher takes the place of a system service that accepts requests to launch applications, and its purpose is to permit an attached debugger to automatically interact with code that would ordinarily be launched in a child process. The child processes are themselves .NET applications.

When this tool was made (years ago), the first thing that was investigated was whether there might be any way to launch a child process with the current debugger *already attached to it*. None was found, and so instead the tool creates an independent `AppDomain` within which to launch each process, then loads the application as an assembly and calls its entry method. This is *almost* working perfectly, but the problem I'm running into is that if those child processes call `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, they get the debug dispatcher tool's command-line instead of the command-line intended to be passed into a child process.

I have been trying to find a way to override `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.

- Based on the publicly-available source code, it looks like if my application were .NET Core, there would in fact be an internal method `SetCommandLineArgs` I could invoke via reflection. The fact that this is internal isn't particularly troubling to me as this tool is specifically a *debug assistant*; if it happens to break down the road because the implementation changed, so be it. It serves no purpose whatsoever outside of a debugging context and won't ever be on a non-dev machine. But... .NET Core and .NET 5 don't support AppDomains at all, and never will, so that's a non-starter.
- I have tried using Ryder to redirect `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` to my own implementation, but it doesn't seem to work, even with a `.ini` file specifying a `[.NET Framework Debugging Control]` section with `AllowOptimize=0`. It almost looks as though the JIT has special handling for this specific method, because even though the reference source shows it making an icall into a native method, when I request disassembly of the JIT output in the debugger, it shows no calls at all, simply loading a value directly from an inlined memory address.
- I searched for ways to change the current process's command-line at the Win32 level, but that appears to be unmodifiable.

In the context of supporting multiple concurrent *applications* inside the same process by means of AppDomains (solely for assisting debugging), is there any way to intercept and/or override the return value of `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, so that I can support hosting applications that obtain their command-line arguments exclusively via that method?

Comment: Regarding not seeing a call, I wonder if what I'm observing is actually a debugger bug. I have a breakpoint on the line in question, and when I Alt+8 to get disassembly, it shows: `INT 3` / `ADC EAX, 5CB27493h`. I think what I'm seeing is the `INT 3` that the debugger inserted to get a breakpoint, and it's disassembling it in that form instead of in the restored form it's supposed to put there as part of entering break mode.

Comment: Ahh, indeed, if I move the breakpoint to the preceding line, then _that_ line becomes an `INT 3` followed by a random instruction, and the one I actually want to break at shows a call instruction.

Comment: Further update: It appears that Ryder redirections in 64-bit contexts seem a bit finnicky. I couldn't figure out exactly what scenarios led to the redirection working and which not. When I switched the process to force itself to run as a 32-bit process always, the redirections approach seemed to become a bit more reliable. Could actually work, maybe!

Comment: Hmm, except the assembler instructions I copy/pasted before _were_ 32-bit instructions...

Comment: Okay, I'm not completely crazy, I just found a Notepad window where I copy/pasted the call from disassembly while trying to figure out why the Ryder redirect wasn't working, and the copy/pasted disassembly is 64-bit. So maybe it was right around the time that I switched from a 64-bit to 32-bit host process that it started working reliably. *shrug*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well, I'm not sure what I did that changed it, but at some point redirecting `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs` using Ryder seemed to go from being unreliable (some calls would redirect, others wouldn't -- in some debug sessions, Ryder seemed to have no effect at all) to reliable (every call gets redirected). Ryder's redirection apparently doesn't automatically apply in all AppDomains, so I have to reinstall it each time I create an AppDomain, after which my experience has been that the process dies a messy death if I try to unload the AppDomain. But, for debug purposes... I think it's adequate.